# How can I decrease Severity?

Tags: plague-inc-evolved

In Plague Inc: Evolved, your disease slowly gains Severity (a yellow bar at the bottom) as you evolve certain traits (such as symptoms). The higher your Severity, the more likely the world will take action.

One of my main strategies if I'm not going for shortest time is to wait until everyone is infected, then kill them off. However, certain disease types (such as Neurax Worm) raise Severity even if you don't evolve symptoms. This can be a problem if the world starts researching a cure too early.

What traits can I evolve to decrease the Severity of my disease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maintain low severity by devolving any symptoms you mutate. The only other way to reduce severity if you are a Bio-Weapon or a Parasite as they both have traits that can be evolved to reduce severity.

EDIT: Forgot about Neurax Worm being able to reduce severity (Stolen from Rokk's answer)

Answer (score 1):

For the Neurax worm, certain symptoms actually decrease severity. Most notably, the first few symptoms down the lower left path (such as [Occipital Mesh](http://plagueinc.wikia.com/wiki/Occipital_Mesh)) decrease severity, unless indicated otherwise.

If you are going for a stealthy approach with the Neurax worm, make sure you evolve these symptoms. And keep transmissions to a minimum, as the Neurax Worm's transmissions increase your severity.